# Solving non-linear fractional differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fractional-calculus, fractional-differential-equations

I want to solve the non-linear Caputo-type fractional equation of the form ($0 < \alpha < 1$)

$$ ^cD^{\alpha}_0 f(t) = af(t)^4 + bf(t) + c$$

I have found, the equation $^cD^{\alpha}_0 f(t) = af(t) + g(t)$ is the Cauchy-type equation and is solved. But, setting $g(t) = af(t)^4 + c$ doesn't work.

Just for clarification, I want something like $f(t) =$ something in $t$. (Numerical solutions / Hints is also fine).Thanks in advance!

PS: If Riemann-Liouville or any other fractional derivatives will make it easier, that's also fine.

PS2: I am a newbie to fractional calculus, so I have no clue other than this book.

Ref:

*Kilbas, Anatoly A.; Srivastava, Hari M.; Trujillo, Juan J.*, Theory and applications of fractional differential equations, North-Holland Mathematics Studies 204. Amsterdam: Elsevier (ISBN 0-444-51832-0/hbk). xv, 523 p. (2006). [ZBL1092.45003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1092.45003).

Comment: [here is a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111391/301977) which is IMO a bit simpler than your equation. Please note that pursuing an analytic solution of even the simplest forms of fractional differential equations is usually a waste of time, because there is none. So your best bet is a numerical solution. To find a numerical solution of a FDE, it is often converted to its discrete-time equivalent. Among the discretization methods for FDEs, the [Grunwald-Letnikov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCnwald%E2%80%93Letnikov_derivative) definition is the most famous one.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully solved numerically a [different fractional differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636648/fractional-bernoulli-equation-and-logistic-function) (FDE) by using the Matlab code to solve FDEs by Prof. R. Garrappa. At the link, see the answer with the plot for the code and paper. I hope this helps.